# Persisting input language when switching tabs on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, language

Is there any way to have either windows or chrome remember and switch the current input language whenever I switch tabs?

> e.g. open a tab on Facebook, switch to French input, open another tab on
>   Stack Overflow, switch back to English input, go back to the Facebook tab and
>   have either systems switch the input language back to French automatically for me.

I noticed there's an extension for chrome called [language-keeping-tabs](https://code.google.com/p/language-keeping-tabs/) but it uses an NPAPI plugin which soon will be no longer supported by Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script that runs continuously in the background and keeps track of what was the input language for each tab. Whenever you switch a tab, the script will restore the input language. You can easily get such a script written for you, including instructions for installing dependencies, using ChatGPT.

Comment: Do not answer a question with a recommendation on ChatGPT for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with you OS language.

You CAN change your language via Settings > Advanced > Languages, but in my experience it doesn't always work as it should.

The best way is to change your OS Display Language to French. I don't know whether you're on PC or Mac or something else, but you might figure this one out yourself.

Also keep in mind that some websites use your location to set the language for you.

Answer (score 0):

This solution should also work in any other modern, standards-compliant browser.

I would install Facebook and Stack Overflow as separate applications ([PWA](https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/)). In Chrome, you click on "Create shortcut" like so:

[image: create site PWA shortcut in Chrome]

And select "Open as window":

[image]

By doing this you will accomplish:

- Separate language for this application window
- Quick/easy switch to the application by means of your operating system
- Pin web shortcuts to your task manager and free these tabs for good

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The app uses the same language as Chrome, and changing the language in the app changes it in Chrome and vice versa.

Comment: Which OS you use? There should be an option to persist language per application or window in the OS language settings. You should choose per window option.

Comment: It's Windows 10 and I have this option enabled but it doesn't help. Looks like the OS treats Chrome and this shortcut as the same app.